# error flask: no moduled named 'markupsafe._compat'

Tags: python, flask

este es el error completo:

```
(flask_env) C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com>index.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\index.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 624, in <module>
    from markupsafe import Markup, escape, soft_unicode
  File "C:\Users\pcort\Documents\tuMicrofono.com\flask_env\lib\site-packages\markupsafe\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from markupsafe._compat import text_type, string_types, int_types, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'markupsafe._compat'
```

que es producido por la siguiente  código

```
from flask import Flask

@app.route('/') 

def index():
    return "Hello, World!" 

app.run()
```

Comment: puedes agregar mas detalles del problema?

Comment: que mas? esta el problema entero.

Comment: Y eso te lo genera que código?, así se hace muy difícil.

Comment: ese error normalmente es que te faltan dependencias https://pypi.org/project/MarkupSafe/

Answer (score 1):

Te falta iniciar el objeto app por lo que veo, tu codigo deberia ser algo asi

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def index():
    return "Hello, World!" 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta instalando el paquete vía `pip install markupsafe` ,

también checkea este post en [github](https://github.com/rdickert/project-quicksilver/issues/6)

> A tu ejemplo le hace falta la linea `app = Flask(__name__)`, tenlo en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

En la ubicación de tu variable de entrono (en tu caso es `flask_env`) `/Lib/site-packages`, elimina de ahí todo lo relacionado a `markupsafe`.

Un vez eliminado vuelve a instalar el `markupsafe` de esta manera:

```
easy_install markupsafe
```

O

```
pip install markupsafe
```

Esto ha solucionado mi problema. Quizás sea un poco tarde para ti, pero posiblemente ayude a alguien mas.